# Using GPS coordinates to modify the center of a map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gps, location

I want to use a function to get location using GPS and than use the coordinates(longitude and latitude) to modify the center of the map .

Here is a part of my code:

```
var lat;
var longi;

function initialize() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onGeoSuccess, onGeoError, {
            maximumAge: 3000,
            enableHighAccuracy: true
        });

        function onGeoSuccess(event) {
            lat = event.coords.latitude;
            longi = event.coords.longitude;
            alert(lat + ', ' + longi);
        }

        function onGeoError(event) {
            lat = 50;
            longi = 150;
        }
    } else {
        lat = 50;
        longi = 150;
    };

    var array;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, longi),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        zoomControl: true
    });
}
```

The problem is:The Alert is fine ,it displays the actual longitude and latitude but the map doesn't appear it gives just a small question mark.

Any help is aprreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `map.setCenter(lat,longi);`

try:

`map.set('center', new google.maps.LatLng(lat, longi));`

Answer (score 2):

You need to center map in `onGeoSuccess` method:

Firs of all move `map` variable higher:

```
var lat, longi, map;
```

Then on `onGeoSuccess` method add `setCenter` method call:

```
function onGeoSuccess(event){
    lat=event.coords.latitude;
    longi=event.coords.longitude;
    map.setCenter( new google.maps.LatLng(lat, longi) );
}
```

And do that wherever you change `lat, longi` values, in `onGeoError` method too.

Also is better to use some default values for `lat, longi`:

```
var lat = 50, 
  longi = 150, 
  map;
```

And move map initialization upper (don't forget to remove `var` statement before `map = new google.maps.Map` line):

```
function initialize() {

    var array;
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, longi),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        zoomControl: true
    });
// rest of your code
```